# How to target a child widget that is contained within multiple parent widgets in order to change the properties?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

A client needs the application to have colour inserted into the application for specific instances, so the fields will only be populated with colour when necessary, I'm doing this with a right-click context menu.

I created an example application that uses this code and pulls the widget names from a JSON file.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hHandle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE widgetName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE colourNumber AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH Results-WidgetList:
    ASSIGN
        widgetName = Results-WidgetList.tt-widName /* these assignments are just getting the info */
        colourNumber = INT(Results-WidgetList.tt-colour)
        .
    hHandle = SESSION:FIRST-CHILD.
    DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE(hHandle):
        IF hHandle:TYPE = "FIELD-GROUP" THEN LEAVE.
        hHandle = hHandle:FIRST-CHILD.
    END.

    hHandle = hHandle:FIRST-CHILD.
    DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE(hHandle):
        IF hHandle:TYPE = "FILL-IN" AND hHandle:NAME = widgetName THEN LEAVE.
        hHandle = hHandle:NEXT-SIBLING.
    END.

    ASSIGN
        hHandle:BGCOLOR = colourNumber.

END.
```

This worked perfectly fine in my example application, but once I try implement it in the main application it can't see the specific widgets because it is looping through the topmost parent container and going no further.

Is there a way to get to the elements that are contained within?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are loading stuff from a JSON file and you don't show that so I can't really comment on it.  But, in general, you need to "Walk the widget tree". The following snippet might be helpful:

```
/* walk the widget tree so that we can update the dcolor for the named field
 */
        
procedure tweakTree:
                 
  define input parameter w     as handle    no-undo.
  define input parameter wName as character no-undo.
  define input parameter dClr  as integer   no-undo.
  
  define variable n as handle no-undo.

  n = w:first-child no-error.
  if valid-handle( n ) then
    run tweakTree( n, wName, dClr ).
  
  n = w:next-sibling no-error.
  if valid-handle( n ) then
    run tweakTree( n, wName, dClr ).
   
  if w:type = "fill-in" and w:name = wName then
    do:
      if session:window-system = "tty" then
        w:dcolor  = dClr.
       else
        w:fgcolor = dClr.
    end.
            
  return.
  
end.  
    
define variable c1 as character no-undo.
define variable c2 as character no-undo.

form c1 with frame f1.
form c2 with frame f2.

assign
  c1 = "abc"
  c2 = "123"
.

display c1 with frame f1.
display c2 with frame f2.

pause.

run tweakTree( current-window, "c1", 2 ).
run tweaktree( current-window, "c2", 1 ).

pause.
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, unfortunately it doesn't work. It's doing the same thing my code was doing where it only walks through the top most frame and goes no further. It might be a design issue with the application itself.

Apologies for not including the JSON file.

Comment: My example starts with a frame but it doesn't have to. I have updated the answer to use CURRENT-WINDOW as the top of the tree. In your code one problem that I think you have is that you are bailing out too easily.  Those LEAVE statements look, to me, like they will not allow your code to fully walk the tree until it finds what it is looking for.

Comment: If you want a more precise answer than this I think you need to provide more information about your window and it's frames....